# Sort Google+ Photos Albums by name

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos

I'm trying to figure out which folders I backed up with Google?

How do I sort Google+ Photos Albums by name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort by album title in [Picasa Web Albums](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/myphotos?noredirect=1) which shows the same photos/albums as Google+